# Font Awesome will not display in html

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, font-awesome

I'm building a website according to a tutorial online where I use font awesome for the menu icons. Given that the CDN is present in my code along with the keycodes for the different icons, I can't see the icon on my webpage.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="with-device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@5.15.4/css/fontawesome.min.css" integrity="sha384-jLKHWM3JRmfMU0A5x5AkjWkw/EYfGUAGagvnfryNV3F9VqM98XiIH7VBGVoxVSc7" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<section class="header">
    <nav>
        <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.png"></a>
        <div class="nav-links">
            <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </nav>

<div class="text-box">
    <h1>Manipulating the world, bit by bit.</h1>
    <p>Making a website is now one of the easiest thing in the world.</p>
    <a href="" class="hero-btn">Contact Us to know more</a>
</div>        

</section>




</body>
</html>
```

style.css:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
.header{
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(4,9,30,0.7),rgba(4,9,30,0.7)),url(images/banner.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
nav{
    display: flex;
    padding: 2% 6%;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
nav img{
    width: 150px; 
}
.nav-links{
    flex: 1;
    text-align: right;
}
.nav-links ul li{
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 12px;
    position: relative;
}
.nav-links ul li a{
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 13px;
}
.nav-links ul li::after{
    content: '';
    width: 0%;
    height: 2px;
    background: #f44336;
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
.nav-links ul li:hover::after{
    width: 100%;
}
.text-box{
    width: 90%;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    text-align: center;
}
.text-box h1{
    font-size: 40px;
}
.text-box p{
    margin: 10px 0 40px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
}
.hero-btn{
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 12px 34px;
    font-size: 13px;
    background: transparent;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hero-btn:hover{
    border: 1px solid #f44336;
    background: #f44336;
    transition: 1s;
}

nav .fa{
    display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 700px){
    .text-box h1{
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    .nav-links ul li{
        display: block;
    }
    .nav-links{
        position: absolute;
        background: #f44336;
        height: 100vh;
        width: 200px;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        text-align: left;
        z-index: 2;

    }
    nav .fa{
        display: block;
        color: #fff;
        margin: 10px;
        font-size: 22px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .nav-links ul{
        padding: 30px;
    }
}
```

I tried various solutions such as checking whether I was using the right keycodes for the icons in accord with the font awesome version. Can someone help? Thanks in advance

Here's an image of what it is showing right now:
[image: image of where the icon should be showing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your CDN URL to this:

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free@6.1.1/css/all.min.css
```

Worked for me after I changed the version.

Answer (score 0):

Click [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome) Copy the link tag and replace your CDN

Answer (score 0):

Try changing to version 5, thats what I did when it wasn't working on the tutorial.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).